# simple "orange growing" coding to understand class and method

Tags: ruby

```
class OrangeTree
  attr_accessor :treeage, :treeheight, :orangecount

  def initialize(treeage = 0, treeheight = 0)
    @treeage = treeage
    @treeheight = treeheight
    @orangecount = []
  end

  def growing_orange
    @treeage += 1
    if @treeage > 2
      i = @treeage
      i.times do
        @orangecount << Orange.new
      end
      return true
    elsif @treeage > 8
      @orangecount = []
      return false
    end
    puts "#{@orangecount} oranges collected"
  end

  def growing_height
    if @treeheight < 4
      @treeheight = @treeage * 0.5 + @treeheight
    else
      @treeheight
    end
    puts "#{@treeheight} inches grow"
  end
end

a = OrangeTree.new
a.growing_orange
a.growing_height
```

I'm trying to make a practice with ruby coding by going through class and method. I'm trying to make a code that can simulate an orange tree that grow year by year. on its 3rd year to 8th year, the tree should manage to produce oranges correspond to its number of years(3rd year = 3 oranges, 8th year = 8 oranges). And up until 4 th year, the tree will stop grow.
but all that I get is "[] oranges collected,0.5 inches grow". which part of my code that is wrong??

Comment: Call `a.growing_orange` more times and see the results. No orange grows on the first or second year (as `@treeage > 2` is false). From a 'design' point of view I would separate the `age!` side-effects of making the tree older from observing the results ..

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations on learning Ruby.  I think you will find it very rewarding.

I want to expand on @user2864740's comment, which suggests that you "separate the `age!` side-effects of making the tree older from observing the results."  Your methods should either have a side-effect, such as changing a variable or producing output, or should return a value, but not both.  Also, every method should do just one thing.

## A new version of OrangeTree

With that in mind, here's a new version of OrangeTree.  It probably doesn't do exactly what your OrangeTree should do, but that doesn't matter.  It shows how following these principles results in a class that's easier to understand.

```
class OrangeTree

  attr_reader :age

  def initialize(age: 0)
    @age = age
  end

  def new_year
    @age += 1
  end

  def orange_count
    return 0 if @age < 3
    [@age, 8].min
  end

  def height
    [@age, 4].min
  end

  def print_height(out = $stdout)   
    out.puts "#{height} inches grow"
  end

  def print_orange_count(out = $stdout)
    out.puts "#{orange_count} oranges collected"
  end

end
```

This class is understandable and easily testable, because:

- `initialize` allows the age to be set.  This is good for the tests.  `age` is a named argument because `OrangeTree.new(age: 2)` is easier to understand than `OrangeTree.new(2)`.  When the meaning of a bare constant is not evident from the name or usage, named arguments help to make the code clearer.
- `new_year` just increments the age.  It is the only method which changes the state of the tree.  This helps to make the class easier to understand and maintain.
- `orange_count` just calculates the number of oranges based on the age.  It does not store the number of oranges, since it can be calculated based on the age.
- `height` just calculates the height of the tree.  It does not store the height, since it can be calculated based on the age.
- `print_height` just prints the height.  It takes `out` as an argument for the convenience of the unit test.
- `print_orange_count` just prints the number of oranges.  It takes `out` as an argument for the convenience of the unit test.

## The unit test

This is the rspec unit test which shows how easily tested OrangeTree is:

```
require "stringio"

describe OrangeTree do

  it "should start out with 0 age" do
    expect(OrangeTree.new.age).to eq 0
  end

  it "should age" do
    tree = OrangeTree.new
    tree.new_year
    expect(tree.age).to eq 1
  end

  it "should grow to height 4" do
    expect(OrangeTree.new(age: 0).height).to eq 0
    expect(OrangeTree.new(age: 1).height).to eq 1
    expect(OrangeTree.new(age: 2).height).to eq 2
    expect(OrangeTree.new(age: 3).height).to eq 3
    expect(OrangeTree.new(age: 4).height).to eq 4
    expect(OrangeTree.new(age: 5).height).to eq 4
  end

  it "should grow oranges between years 3 and 8" do
    expect(OrangeTree.new(age: 0).orange_count).to eq 0
    expect(OrangeTree.new(age: 1).orange_count).to eq 0
    expect(OrangeTree.new(age: 2).orange_count).to eq 0
    expect(OrangeTree.new(age: 3).orange_count).to eq 3
    expect(OrangeTree.new(age: 4).orange_count).to eq 4
    expect(OrangeTree.new(age: 5).orange_count).to eq 5
    expect(OrangeTree.new(age: 6).orange_count).to eq 6
    expect(OrangeTree.new(age: 7).orange_count).to eq 7
    expect(OrangeTree.new(age: 8).orange_count).to eq 8
    expect(OrangeTree.new(age: 9).orange_count).to eq 8
  end

  it "should print the height" do
    out = StringIO.new
    tree = OrangeTree.new(age: 2)
    tree.print_height(out)
    expect(out.string).to eq "2 inches grow\n"
  end

  it "should print the number of oranges" do
    out = StringIO.new
    tree = OrangeTree.new(age: 4)
    tree.print_orange_count(out)
    expect(out.string).to eq "4 oranges collected\n"
  end

end
```